# Using MonitorEnter : How should i call synchronised method?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

```
void Java_Package_Multithreading_againCallReadFile
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

 if((*env)->MonitorEnter(env,obj) == JNI_OK) {
   printf("Now you can call the synchronised method !");
 } else {
     printf("oops ! Failed to acquire the lock.");
   }
}
```

From the above method i want to check if i can call the method that is synchronised and could be in use by another thread. What does `MonitorEnter` actually check. I have read its documentation but don't understand what it is. What i want to do is ,call that synchronised method after checking if it is safe to call that method. The above method doesn't seem right, because even when the `if` statement is satisfied,I get a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

> "What i want to do is, call that synchronised method after checking if
>   it is safe to call that method."

This doesn't make any sense. Just call it. If the method is already synchronized you aren't adding any value whatsoever. Calling 'MonitorEnter' doesn't 'check if it is safe to call that method' at all. It claims the lock on the object you supply.

Comment: but then i get a fatal error if call that synchronised function which could be sleeping or doing it's work

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html) doing MonitorEnter(env, obj) is like using native java [synchronizatioin statement on object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

```
synchronized (obj) {
    ... // synchronized block
}
```

so in your example you are using `this` as synchronization object and this should be okay I think. But do not forget to use MonitorExit() at the end of the call.

What is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: But what is the content of hs_err_pid5536.log? And other dll calls doing normally without any problems?

Comment: [you can check this link. It doesn't help me](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/hs_err_pid5536.log)